# Hyperledger Composer PeerAdmin Network Admin Centralization?

Tags: admin, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

From my current understanding, which I have to admit is slightly limited so far, to deploy a Business Network on Fabric I will need a PeerAdmin and a NetworkAdmin.
These Admins would be managed by one authority each.
For an actual Business-Network how can I build a Network without having these central authorities?

Is it possible do delete the admincards after deployment to create a decentralized network?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger tools allow you to build permissioned blockchains. By design, you will always have *some* centralization. Let's start by a few definitions :

- In Hyperledger, peers identity are divided between **administrators** and **members**. [The documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/bnd-deploy) explains the difference between them as follow : administrators identity give permission to install Hyperledger Fabric chaincode (smart contract) for a new business network onto peers. Members do not have permission to install chaincode, they just use it.
- In order to deploy a business network to a set of peers, you need at least an **identity** that has administrative rights to all of those peers, ie an administrator. PeerAdmin is the name of the peer administrator of most Hyperledger Fabric v1.1 network samples. You do not need to have two distinct administrators (PeerAdmin and NetworkAdmin in your question) but it is a good practice (see [Step 4](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/developer-tutorial))
- Now, the Hyperledger **Certificate Authority** (CA) is [a component](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html) managing identities and transactions. It is a key component of Hyperledger and you can not suppress it.

To answer your question :

> For an actual Business-Network how can I build a Network without having these central authorities?

You will need at least one administrator identity to deploy your network.

> Is it possible do delete the admincards after deployment to create a decentralized network?

If you delete the cards, you'll just delete admin identities. It won't make a decentralized network on its own. If you want to move further, Hyperledger allows you to decentralize membership administration. Some ways are listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704301/how-to-achieve-decentralized-membership-in-hyperledger-fabric-1-0?rq=1).